# Find the joint distribution of the following random vectors (X, Y); (X, Z); (Y, Z) and (X, Y, Z).

Tags: probability-distributions

A box contains eight balls numbered from 1 to 8. The first four are red and the other white. We select the balls randomly from the box and define the following variables: X is the number of white balls in the sample, Y the number of even numbers and Z the number of balls in the sample whose number is less than 6. Find the joint distribution of the following random vectors (X, Y); (X, Z); (Y, Z) and (X, Y, Z). Study the independence of these variables.

I'm having trouble trying to define the variables. Here's how I think it should be:

$\Omega= \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ 
$$X=\{1 \ \text{if} \ x=\{5,6,7,8\}, 0 \ o.c.\}\\
Y=\{1 \ \text{if} \ y=\{2,4,6,8\}, 0 \ o.c.\} \\
Z=\{1 \ \text{if} \ z=\{1,2,3,4,5\}, 0 \ o.c.\} $$

Comment: We select the balls without replacement, do we. How many balls do we take?

Comment: We take two balls.

Comment: With or without replacement? If you want answers and attention then pls ask your question more carefully.